# R: Why is this matrix not numeric while everything in it is numeric?

Tags: r, matrix

I got a weird problem. Look at this matrix:

```
 theta2
      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       
 [1,] 0.1024147  0.0111102  -0.08898407
 [2,] -0.2182463 0.02381744 0.1164061  
 [3,] -2.160951  -0.1846134 -0.2051436 
 [4,] -1.915053  -0.2106328 -0.2388602 
 [5,] -1.989786  -0.2017471 -0.2244937 
 [6,] -2.013182  -0.1923669 -0.2284833 
 [7,] -2.184123  -0.174379  -0.209156  
 [8,] -2.052668  -0.1971675 -0.2291237 
 [9,] -2.108423  -0.1987345 -0.2421515 
[10,] -2.066361  -0.2162237 -0.2430083
```

Everything is numeric. We look at its class:

```
     class(theta2)
[1] "matrix"
```

No problem it's a matrix. And we look at its structure:

```
str(theta2)
List of 30
 $ : num 0.102
 $ : num -0.218
 $ : num -2.16
 $ : num -1.92
 $ : num -1.99
 $ : num -2.01
 $ : num -2.18
 $ : num -2.05
 $ : num -2.11
 $ : num -2.07
 $ : num 0.0111
 $ : num 0.0238
 $ : num -0.185
 $ : num -0.211
 $ : num -0.202
 $ : num -0.192
 $ : num -0.174
 $ : num -0.197
 $ : num -0.199
 $ : num -0.216
 $ : num -0.089
 $ : num 0.116
 $ : num -0.205
 $ : num -0.239
 $ : num -0.224
 $ : num -0.228
 $ : num -0.209
 $ : num -0.229
 $ : num -0.242
 $ : num -0.243
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 10 3
```

A bit weird that why it is "list of 30"?
More weird is when I checked if it's numeric:

```
is.numeric(theta2)
[1] FALSE
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here? I am not a newbie but I totally get lost!

Comment: How did you create this "matrix"? What you really have appears to be a dimensioned list.

Comment: @MrFlick You are right. This is like a R-trap. Last time I spent a whole day to figure out in order to do matrix operations with a matrix taken from a dataframe you need to convert! This time with list. OMG:)

Comment: Well, you still haven't said how you created such an object. It's likely that there's a problem with your code that generates this "thing". You shouldn't have to use the code in the answer if you created the object correctly in the first place.

Comment: @MrFlick I first minimized a function with optimx. Suppose the problem has n independent variables, then the first n columns of the optimx result are the solution. Then I transformed it to a matrix by matrix(solution, 10, 3) and got theta2 you have seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, you created a matrix from `list`

```
set.seed(25)
theta2 <- as.list(rnorm(30))

dim(theta2) <- c(10,3)
class(theta2)
#[1] "matrix"

str(theta2, list.len=3)
# List of 30
#$ : num -0.212
#$ : num -1.04
#$ : num -1.15
#[list output truncated]
# - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 10 3

is.numeric(theta2)
#[1] FALSE
```

As it is a `list`, you can check the `is.numeric` with `lapply/sapply`

```
 sapply(theta2, is.numeric)
```

You could `unlist` the `theta2` and create a `matrix` with the proper dimensions

```
theta2N <- unlist(theta2)
dim(theta2N) <- c(10,3)
is.matrix(theta2N)
#[1] TRUE
is.numeric(theta2N)
#[1] TRUE
```